# Extend an external application Style/Theme

Tags: android, attributes, android-resources, android-theme

I want to define an android style that extends one defined in a different Application/package not imported as library.

From the definition of an xml reference to an android resource [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html#ResourcesFromXml):

```
@[<package_name>:]<resource_type>/<resource_name>
```

seems that is possible to specify an external  where the resource is defined ( as used to reference system resource *@android:string/name* )

Now, i have my main app ( package: *com.example.test* ) that define an attribute and a theme like this:

```
<declare-styleable name="TestAttrs">
    <attr name="testColor" format="color" />
</declare-styleable>

<style name="TestTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme">
    <item name="testColor">#FFFF0000</item>
</style>
```

if in a second, different app I try to use the previous package to define a style using the syntax shown above I get an error saying that the resouce can't be found.

```
 <style name="SubTheme" parent="@com.example.test:style/TestTheme">
    <item name="com.example.test:testColor">#FF00FF00</item>
 </style>
```

is it possible to tell the compiler where to look for the package?

do i have to define my initial style/attributes as shared?

Answer (score 0):

Did you declare the namespace:

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
           xmlns:com.example.test="...external resource's namespace">
```

Comment: how would you define the external resouces namespace? i tried like this: "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.example.test"

Comment: Not sure, do you have access to the external code? It should be there. For example, for admob, I had to do `xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"`

Comment: yes i do have access. For the moment i'm only playing with test projects to get it to work before starting to seriusly work with it.

Answer (score 0):

`package_name` does not refer to external applications on the device, but other library-project packages you are building against (each have their own resource table, which is then merged).

To access private resources in external applications you can use [`PackageManager.getResourcesForApplication()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#getResourcesForApplication%28java.lang.String%29) or expose a ContentProvider and do it yourself.

Comment: ok, i knew i could take resource by code but i'd need to access them by xml. Do you know a way to expose known external package to xml namespace?

Comment: There is no way (that I know of).

Comment: i was asking it cause of this powerAmp skin project: https://github.com/maxmpz/powerampapi/blob/master/poweramp_skin_sdk/two_skins/res/values/skin2_styles.xml they are doing it. But i don't get how they made it build.

Comment: Looks like they're setting the ids in each skin's public.xml, and then referencing them in the app by called PackageManager.getResourcesForApplication() and then using the id (0x80050000, etc).